# How to get data from smart-table plugin?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am trying to adapt the example of how to use a custom plugin with smart-table. See the "Create your own plugin" section of http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Here is a screen shot of my web app so far:

[image]

The problem I have is that I do not know how to get the items select from the smart-table.  The selected items on the smart-table are "Beer" and "Mountain Biking".  Here's my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['smart-table']);

app.directive('csSelect', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        template: '<input type="checkbox"/>',
        scope: {
            row: '=csSelect'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

            element.bind('change', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.select(scope.row, 'multiple');
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('row.isSelected', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === true) {
                    element.parent().addClass('st-selected');
                } else {
                    element.parent().removeClass('st-selected');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller("vendorCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.vendor_to_look_for = "";
    $scope.newvendor = "";
    $scope.newlogo = "";
    $scope.vendors_types = [];

    $scope.itemsByPage=5;
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/vendor").then(function(response) {
        $scope.all_vendors = response.data;
    });
    $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/type").then(function(response) {
        $scope.all_types = response.data;
    });


    $scope.submit_vendor  = function() {
        // alert("add new vendor [" + $scope.newvendor + "]" );
        var data = $.param({ vendor_name: $scope.newvendor, vendor_logo: $scope.newlogo, vendors_types: $scope.vendors_types });
        $http.post("http://192.168.1.115:8080/vendor/add",
            // [{'vendor': $scope.newvendor}],
            data,
            {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
        });
        $http.get("http://192.168.1.115:8080/vendor").then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.all_vendors = response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Update: Here's the pertinent HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submit_vendor()">
      <table>
      <tr><td><label>Vendor name</label></td><td><input type="text" ng-model="newvendor" placeholder="Name"></td></tr>
      <tr><td><label>Logourl</label></td><td><input type="text" ng-model="newlogo" placeholder="Url"></td></tr>
      </table>
      <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="all_types" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th st-sort="type">Select</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in displayedCollection">
                  <td cs-select="x"></td>
                  <td>{{x.type}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
                      <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
      </table>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Add </button>
</form>
```

When I click the add button my submit_vendor() function executes but my the `vendor_types` I pass in my form data is empty.  How do I get the items selected in my table into my form data?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code where you have used your directive. May be you need to pass vendors_types there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Partha.  I have updated my OP with the HTML where I use my directive.

Comment: How would I pass vendor_types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model 
This makes things a lot easier.  I do not need to declare my `csSelect` directive :)